# For which values of $b = [b_1;b_2;b_3]$ is $Ax=b$ consistent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

Let$$ A = 
    \begin{pmatrix}
    2 & -1 & -13 \\
    5 & -2 & -31 \\
    -2 & 4 & 22 \\
    \end{pmatrix} $$

For which values of $$b = 
    \begin{pmatrix}
    b_1\\
    b_2 \\
    b_3 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
is $Ax = b$ consistent ? 
I tried to set the matrix in augmented form 
$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  2&-1&-13&b1\\
  5&-2&-31&b2\\
  -2&4&22&b3
\end{array}
\right] $$
and then reduce it to get 
$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
  1&0&-25/2&(21b1)/2-4b2\\
  0&1&3&-5b1+2b2\\
  0&0&0&16b1-6b2+b3
\end{array}
\right] $$
I know that 
16b1-b2+b3 = 0 for Ax=b to be consistent, but the question seems to be asking about the values of b1,b2,b3 ?

Comment: What have you tried?  Presumably the determinant of $A$ is $0$ or the answer would be all of them.  Then find the nullspace of $A$

Comment: What have you tried? If you show you have put in some effort to solve the problem then people are more likely to answer your question

Comment: I tried to reduce the matrix and I got R3 0 0 0 | 16b1 - 6b2 + b3

Comment: I know in this case that for the system to be consistent, 16b1 - 6b2 + b3 must = 0
but the question seems to be asking for values of b1 b2 b3

Comment: Reduce what matrix? [Edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3544082/edit) your question and add some more detail about the steps you took

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $16b_1-6b_2+b_3=0$ when $b=[3;8;0]$, e.g.

Comment: I got $-5$ where you got $-25/2$; and did you mean $16b_1-\color{red}6b_2+b_3=0$ for $Ax=b$ to be consistent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $Ax$ is the linear combination of the columns of $A$ with the coefficients of $x$, one can have $Ax=b$ precisely when $b$ is some linear combination of those columns, in other words when it is in their span. That is already a correct answer, but you can try to describe that span more precisely; three vectors in $\Bbb R^3$ often span the whole space so if that were the case, you could just say "always". But these columns happen not to, so you could try to find either a basis or (better) an equation describing the span. (An equation is better, because you can immediately apply it to a candidate en tell without further ado whether the system is consistent for it.)

Comment: Thank You, Professor!